# Python converting string date object to date gives valuerror

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert string date object to date object in python.
I did this so far

```
 old_date = '01 April 1986' 
 new_date = datetime.strptime(old_date,'%d %M %Y')
 print new_date
```

But I get the following error.

> ValueError: time data '01 April 1986' does not match format '%d %M %Y'

Any guess?

Comment: You could've referred to the [docs](http://strftime.org/) to check if the format specifier was valid

Comment: You could also have used the same format specifier with `strftime` on a known date and look at the output. That would point at the problem as well.

Answer (score 4):

`%M` parses *minutes*, a numeric value, not a month. Your date specifies the month as `'April'`, so use `%B` to parse a *named* month:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> old_date = '01 April 1986' 
>>> datetime.strptime(old_date,'%d %B %Y')
datetime.datetime(1986, 4, 1, 0, 0)
```

From the [*`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> `%B`
>   Month as locale’s full name.
>   January, February, ..., December (en_US);
>   Januar, Februar, ..., Dezember (de_DE)
>
> `%M`
>   Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
>   00, 01, ..., 59

Answer (score 0):

You can first guess the type of date format the string is using and then convert to the same system recognised date format.
I wrote a simple date_tools utilities that you can find here at [https://github.com/henin/date_tools/]

#### Installation: pip install date-tools

#### Usage:

> from date_tools import date_guesser
>
> from datetime import datetime
>
> old_date = '01 April 1986'
>
> date_format = date_guesser.guess_date_format(old_date)
>
> new_date = datetime.strptime(old_date, date_format)
>
> print(new_date)